# How to check list of objects one property value count using AssertJ?

Tags: java, junit4, spring-junit, assertj

```
class Test{
private Boolean isChange;

}
Assume that tests list contains 1000 objets.

List<Test> tests = new ArrayList<Test>();
Test t  = new Test();
t.setIschange(true);
tests.add(t);
```

like that I have added 200 objects as true i.e isChanges value, remaining all are false out of 1000; and it will change to 300 like.

so how to check wheather list contains 200 objects isChange value is true using assertJ

Answer (score 3):

You can use [filter](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-features-highlight.html#filters) if you have a proper getter to access the value, or use a lambda:

```
assertThat(tests).filteredOn("change", true).hasSize(200);
```

Comment: Lambdas are probably better than reflection getting access, but of course, that's only possible for Java 8.